# Need solution to search case insensitive fields, REACT, sailis , mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, waterline, sails-mongo

Adapter i am using is

**adapter: "sails-mongo",**

I am trying to query for matches,
example: Assume Values in DB for **field (name)** are **JOHN , John, JohN , john, JOhn martin**

If i search with a query for **name="john"** results should **JOHN, John, johN**

In the below code i need solution with **name: inputs.name** case insensitive search

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
let criteria = {
  name: inputs.name,
  deleteflag: false,
};

if (inputs.id) {
  criteria = {
    ...criteria,
    _id: { "!=": inputs.id },
  };
}

var existinPerson = await Person.find({
  where: criteria,
});
if (existinPerson && existinPerson.length) {
  return exits.success({ isPersonUnique: false });
} else {
  return exits.success({ isPersonUnique: true });
}
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used
`name: { like: inputs.marketName },` instead of `name: inputs.name,` and for fetching i used `.meta({ makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true })`...
Finally this solution worked well for my scenario
`var existinPerson = await Person.find({ where: criteria, }).meta({ makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true });`